# Creating custom application icon android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons

I am working on an application and now I want to create a custom app icon for that like this :

[image: this]

A main icon and an another icon at one corner (as in attached image a calling image as main and contact image as in the top right corner).
I know we can use Image Asset to create application icons but icon the way i want can't be created using Image Asset. So what is the other way? Can somebody guide me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can see this Link

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html

Comment: You can overlap image over another image using RelativeLayout

Comment: Mentioned already in the post I know using Image Asset Studio. For passing the image to the studio first i need have the image. My question is how do i create that image? Maybe some photoshop as to be used it seems. If you have any idea about that please post the links. Thanks.

Comment: @Naveen, Yeah know about how to have images overlapped using RelativeLayout. Can you please lemme know how to use those image as a app launcher icon? thanks

Comment: You can do this as explained in below answer ... check it

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **drawble.xml** for your icon.
Try adding two `ImageView` in a `RelativeLayout` with your pictures ( with additional size and positions ) and then, in `AndroidManifest.xml` set **drawble.xml** for you project's icon.

**res/drawble/custom_icon.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/dial"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/contact"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
 ...
<application
    android:icon="@drawble/custom_icon"
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Can you please tell me how do i get these icon sizes/clarity as per the android developer guideline?

Comment: you can use `px` instead `dp` alongside different size .. 32/48/72/94/144 px

Comment: You mean have to create individual drawable.xml for each screen density( Like we have individual images supporting different screens) ?

Comment: Yes ... exactly ... put them in separated folders as we did for normal images ( icons ) @Shree

Comment: Sure, I'll try this mean while if you know any other better way of achieving this lemme know. Thanks.

Comment: OK ... also accept answer if it was helpful :) @Shree

Comment: sure I'll if your suggested approach satisfies our requirement@ Arash

Comment: Can you tell me how to use RelativeLayout in xml defined in drawable folder? I am getting the error "Element RelativeLayout must be declared"

Comment: because you cannot use relative layout in drawable

Comment: @Nagendra, Exactly then How do create an icon as per  my requirement? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can somebody help?

Comment: try creating the image in any photo editing tool and export it as vector ,now you can use it!